# How to use ".Where" condition with Json object in c#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, where-clause

I'm working on a Xamarin project (with Newtonsoft.Json). Trying to deserialize a json and use it (all and some part of json).

I have a json list a class for it. I can list all the list but I can't select from the list such as; where "age > 40".

My json;

```
{"data":
    [
    {
    "contact_id":"1",
    "contact_date":"2020-02-19",
    "contact_stat":"new"
    }
    ,
    {
    "contact_id":"2",
    "contact_date":"2020-02-19",
    "contact_stat":"old"
    }
    ,
    {
    "contact_id":"3",
    "contact_date":"2020-02-19",
    "contact_stat":"new"
    }
    ]
}
```

My class;

```
public class AllSource
{
    public string contact_id{ get; set; }
    public DateTime contact_date{ get; set; }
    public string contact_stat{ get; set; }
}
public class AllList
{
    public List<AllSource> data { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this in my .cs => This way I can use all of them;

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://example.com/json2.asp");
string itemJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
AllList ObjJson = new AllList();
   if (itemJson != "")
       {
          ObjJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllList>(itemJson);
          mydata = ObjJson.data;
       }
```

I'm trying something like this (want to get only "stat=new");

```
ObjJson.Where(x => x.stat == "new");
```

But I get this error;

> AllList does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type could be found.

Tried so many suggestions but could not managed. Hope I explained my problem clearly.

Comment: `ObjJson.data.Where(x => x.contact_stat == "new");` you need to filter the `data` which is the list of `AllSource`.

Comment: You are trying to filter the class `AllList` and you cant, thats the reason for the error.

Comment: OMG. I'm a idiot. How can't I see that. I need to sleep. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var filteredData = ObjJson.data.Where(x => x.contact_stat == "new");
```

Comment: Thanks so much. All my fault is not sleeping for two days. Thanks so much again.